# How to install NodeJS package node-parquet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, parquet

I tried installing node package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-parquet) on CentOS and on Ubuntu with different Node versions but it keep failing.

```
npm i node-parquet

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-parquet@0.2.7 preinstall: `./build_parquet-cpp.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-parquet@0.2.7 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How to make it work?

Comment: You probably should [read the installation requirements.](https://github.com/skale-me/node-parquet#build-install).

Comment: @Neil Lunn - Tried with requirements but still failing. I'll give you $30 if you make installation on RHEL EC2 :)

Comment: If you don't have a clearer log, try running the build_parquet-cpp.sh file directly and see if it presents a better error log on what you're missing. You really should look through the installation requirements again and see if something is missed, like you have Python 3 instead of Python 2, or node-gyp is not installed, etc